# How to configure Solr for User ip details

Tags: apache, logging, solr, httpd.conf

I am using solr 4.10.3. Remote users access it through a url and run their specific queries like in search engines. I want to know IP address along with queries run by users. In solr log file, details of queries are there but no information about user ip. I am using httpd (apache) webserver.

Or

if I analyze apache webserver log, there I get informations about ips etc but no information about query. So How I can configure httpd configuration so that its log also include queries details.

Anyone of two will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you're using Apache httpd to directly serve content from Solr (since it's usually served by either the bundled jetty or a different java application server (such as Tomcat) if you've installed it that way), but you can configure [Apache httpd's log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) through the [LogFormat directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat).

```
   %q   The query string (prepended with a ? if a query 
        string exists, otherwise an empty string).
```

The other option is to configure Solr's logging properly, see [Configuring Logging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging), but depending on your setup (if you're proxying requests), that might not include the originating IP address (and just the address of the proxy server).